# IFrame vs Ajax for a dialog?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, ajax

At present, when I wish to display a dialog to a user, say to edit an object that's been selected from the main window, I create a jQueryUI Dialog and insert an iframe inside of it to the page that handles the editing.

I've found this works very well because the dialog page can have its own scripts,styles, and element IDs. I don't need to concern myself with any conflicts that could arise between my dialog and the parent page.

The only somewhat awkward part I've found is communication between the parent window and the child dialog. Unfortunately the child iframe usually needs to know about its parent. I've found this necessary so it can do things like closing its dialog (which resides in the parent window) or telling the parent to refresh its list of items after a successful edit.

Ideally the child wouldn't be aware of its parent, but the benefits of a standalone page, that can be tested like any other with no conflicts seems worth it.

Still, I often read comments discouraging iframe use. I'm not sure if this is truly not a best practice, or some people simply prefer not to use them.

I'm always looking to improve the way I do things though. If using ajax for this type of thing really is best practice, how is it done for a non trivial dialog?

I can imagine using ajax to request the markup for a dialog and inserting that into the dialog, but I can't figure out how to manage all of the conflicts, scripts, css, element IDs, etc for a complex dialog merging w/ an existing page.

Are there any examples of how this should be done? Or is iframe really better when your dialogs are not very simple?

Thanks for any ideas or help!

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to open just a separate browser window or tab.

Comment: I can't. That would defeat the purpose of a modal dialog and not provide the UI I'm going for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is use the namespace pattern so you do not have any conflicts in your scripts.

So you can have a namespaced object which contains all of your main page's script to something like 
    MyApp.MainController

And similarly one for your dialog
    MyApp.DialogController

As for making sure your jquery selectors do not collide (i.e. get all inputs just for the dialog instead of all of the inputs for the entire page) is to create a new namespaced object to contain the script for your dialog inside your main script and then pass in the dom context you want to scope your calls with. This is often done with javascript MVC pattern when constructing controllers

```
var myDialogController = new MyApp.DialogController($("#my-dialog-container));
```

Inside your namespaced dialog script you can use delegates when creating your scripts and scope them appropriately.

```
myScope.delegate("input", "change", function(e){...})
```

This says "only bind events for input elements which live inside the 'myScope'" element.

Finally for communication from your dialog to your main page you can use query triggers and trigger custom events on your scoped dialog element.

```
myScope.trigger("myDialog.hasTriggeredEvent", dataToSendToMainPage);
```

And in your main script you can listen for that event that was triggered

```
("body").live("myDialog.hasTriggeredEvent", function(e) {
    //do logic here
}
```

Comment: Those are some very interesting ideas Keith. Is it your opinion that this is preferable to using an iframe? If so, why?

Comment: Yes. I feel an iframe is unnecessary. Using namespacing and scoping with your javascript gives you a much more flexible pattern. You don't have to fight against what frames limit you to do as far as communication in and out of the iframe. Browsers put these restrictions in on purpose since browsers need to worry about cross domain security attacks in cases where the iframe loads pages from other places on the internet. I feel frames have there place in some cases but those cases are rare. Lastly, if you want to put your dialog on another page. With this approach it is all plug and play.

Answer (score 0):

One of the intranet apps that I am working with uses this exact same pattern to invoke a maintenance page from another page that has association to the entity being maintained in the dialog.

The reason why it is a separate page for us though, is because it could also be opened directly wherein you might be maintaining a list of such entities (rather than one instance when it has opened under a context).

And so, this diloag with an iframe that loads another page altogether, has been working well for us, especially because of the reuse in the content page.

And as you mentioned, we need to know a few things from the parent, and we pass these as querystrings to the `src` of the iframe.

Having said all that, I did not understand what kind of conflicts would you have when the content is loaded via ajax into a div that opens as a dialog. Could you not limit the context of all the id or css class selectors to the dialog-div and avoid having any conflicts from the parent page at all?

Anyways, I would not know enough to comment which one of these two would be a good or preferred design pattern.

Comment: Well, typically the id of an element in the DOM should always be unique. Though, by scoping searches for the id to the dialog you're right..you could probably get away w/ it even if its not a good idea. One example of a conflict is in the javascript the dialog uses. Typically I have a JS object that acts as a view model and I store cached copied of various jQuery elements. I would be worried about these variables, my methods, etc possibly conflicting w/ those from the main page or another dialog.